# Parsing a set of JSON arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I prepared a JSON file consisting of a set of Arrays and I am not sure if this is the right way as I have no idea how to properly parse it:

```
[{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4"},{"a":"5","b":"6","c":"7","d":"8"}]
```

So it consists of 2 in this example (or more) arrays, set one after 1. So it is not a classic multidimensional JSON array and in each one of those arrays there are the same fields: a,b,c,d...

How do I parse this JSON in JavaScript to access for example item 'c' in second array and to know that this is really item from the 2nd array? I have no idea so far...

Comment: does "JSON.parse" help? if not, perhaps you have an array of objects, rather than JSON already

Comment: Your question is no clear: if you do not know how to parse a json string, you can use `JSON.parse method`. if you do not know how to reach the desired object property, you have to address the right object in the outher array (n-1) and the use the dot notation or the square bracket one to read the desired poperties. for the _c_ prop of the second object  you can use `json[1].c` or `json[1]['c']` (please, note that `'c'` is a string in the second example). The second version is more useful if you don't know in advance the porperty to read

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that your json is a seperate file (eg sample.json)

*sample.json*

```
[{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4"},{"a":"5","b":"6","c":"7","d":"8"}]
```

if you are running your javascript through node you can include your json file as follows:

*test.js*

```
var sample = require('./sample.json');
console.log(sample[0].a);
//"1"
```

running `node test.js` would log '1'